# Would Hashing A Password In Sha512 Using JavaScript Be Secure?

Tags: passwords, sha-2, sha-512, secure-storage

I've created a competition for a few friends of mine that wanted to learn the basics of penetration testing. In said competition, there is one section in which there's a log file you need to check out to find and submit the flag. Since I don't want the players simply looking at the source code and getting the password, and I won't obfuscate the code (I could, I just don't really want to. Not out of laziness, but to not confuse any n00bs). So what I did was encrypted the password with a different site in SHA512 and made it so if you guess a password, it will encrypt it in SHA512 and check whether it's correct or not. Source code for JavaScript is on http://vulnerablesite.freecluster.eu/BoooogityBooogityBOOOO.js
Entire WarGame (CTF Hacking Challenge that's 24/7):
vulnerablesite.freecluster.eu

Comment: SHA512 is neither [an encoding nor encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption#4657456), it is a ([cryptographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)) [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for a game, but it's by no means secure. Use Scrypt or Argon2 for a secure password hashing function. SHA-512 is a general-purpose hash function, it's very fast and uses little memory. For password hashing you want tuneable performance (to slow down brute force) in both time and memory. You also need a unique salt for each password. In your case it sounds like there's only one password, so a salt is less useful, but it's better to get in the habit of doing things properly.

Comment: A salt would also protect against a dictionary lookup, aside from the presumably compromised database. One can argue it is still very useful.

Comment: Thanks, but why'd my question get down voted so much?

Comment: Perhaps the downvotes are due not understanding password security, that no simple hash is sufficient secure as a password verifier.

Comment: I think it's mostly due to not understanding the difference between encryption, encoding and hashing (which is the *key* to your question!), and thinking that Javascript has anything to do with it.

Comment: @RubenDeSmet and true but isn't learning what stack exchange is about, not chastising for asking questions. It may be the basics of password security, but I'm still learning. i also created that site to learn about the basics of cyber security, not to be secure.

Comment: Also I know Javascript has nothing to do with it @RubenDeSmet, I just need to use it for the site